# Semantic consequence

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra

I'm studying refutation trees in computer science II, but I have a big doubt:

Let $\Gamma, \Psi \subseteq F_m$

Is the following hypothesis true?

$\Gamma \vDash \Psi \iff \not\vDash\{\Gamma,\lnot \Psi\} \iff \vDash (\Gamma\rightarrow \Psi) \iff \not \vDash \lnot(\Gamma \rightarrow \Psi)$

i.e.:

Let $A, B, C \subseteq F_m$ such that $\{A\rightarrow B, \lnot B \rightarrow\lnot C\} \vDash A \rightarrow C$

Then, to prove this I can apply:

$\{A\rightarrow B, \lnot B \rightarrow \lnot C, \lnot (A \rightarrow C)\}$ is unsatisfiable $\implies \not \vDash ((A\rightarrow B) \land (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot C) \land \lnot ( A \rightarrow C ) )$

Or I can use:

$\not \vDash \lnot (((A\rightarrow B) \land (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot C)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$

So, this is true?

Thanks!

Comment: I have some problem with the symbols you have used. $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ iff $\{ \Gamma, \lnot \varphi \}$ is *unsatisfiable*. Also $\alpha \vDash \varphi$ iff $\vDash \alpha \rightarrow \varphi$. But, in general, $\Gamma$ is a *set* of sentences; thus, you cannot write $\Gamma \rightarrow \varphi$. Only when $\Gamma$ is *finite*, i.e.$\Gamma = \{ \gamma_1, ... \gamma_n \}$, let $\gamma := \gamma_1 \land ... \land \gamma_n$, thus $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ iff $\vDash \gamma \rightarrow \varphi$.

Answer (score 2):

About your question, it is correct to say that, according to the definition of *logical consequence*, in order to prove that :

> ${A→B,¬B→¬C} \vDash A→C$,

we have to show that :

> $\{ A→B, ¬B→¬C, ¬(A→C) \}$ is *unsatisfiable*.

We have that :

> > $\varphi$ is *unsatisfiable* iff $\lnot \varphi$ is (universally) *valid*.

*Note*. When $\varphi$ is *valid*, we write : $\vDash \varphi$.

A set $\Gamma$ of formulae is *unsatisfiable* iff there is **no** valuation that "makes true" simultaneously **all** formulae in $\Gamma$.

If $\Gamma$ is a *finite* set of ($n$) formulae, this amount to the *unsatisfiability* of the *conjunction* of the formulae $\gamma_i \in \Gamma$, $i \le n$.

Thus, $\Gamma$ *finite* is *unsatisfiable* iff $\lnot (\gamma_1 \land ... \land \gamma_n)$ is *valid*.

In conclusion, $\{ A→B, ¬B→¬C, ¬(A→C) \}$ is *unsatisfiable* iff :

> > $\vDash \lnot ((A→B)∧(¬B→¬C)∧¬(A→C))$.

Comment: So, to prove that $\{A\rightarrow B, \lnot C \rightarrow \lnot B \} \vDash A \rightarrow C$ I must to prove that $\not \vDash \lnot ((A \rightarrow B) \land (\lnot C \rightarrow \lnot B) \land \lnot (A \rightarrow C))$ ?

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez - NO : you have to prove $\vDash \lnot (...)$, i.e.that the negated formula is *valid*.

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez - refutation tree method allows us to conclude that $\varphi$ is a *tautology* when all paths in the finished tree are closed. To show that $\varphi$ is *logical consequence* of $\alpha$, we have to show that $\alpha \rightarrow \varphi$ is *unsatisfiable*. But $\alpha \rightarrow \varphi$ is unsat iff its *negation* $\lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \varphi)$ is valid. Thus, in order to show that $\alpha \vDash \varphi$, we have to "run" the refutation tree for $\lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \varphi)$.